# Delete custom options from products in specific store

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql, custom-options

Within one installation of magento (1.7.0.2) I have 1 website with 2 stores. In store #1 there are 1000 simple products with custom options. In store #2, using Magento Store Manager, I created copies of each 1000 products and was able to changed them to configurable items.

However, now I need to delete the custom options for the items in store #2 since they no longer need custom options as I'll be making associated simple items (to replace the function of custom options). While the store manager makes some tasks very easy to do via the GUI, it doesn't appear to have a simple way of deleting custom options from a group of products.

So, I'm looking for a way to do it via mySQL (phpmyadmin) and any help would be greatful. I searched all over google but all I've found are programmatic ways of adding, which isn't what I need. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The custom options are stored in the table catalog_product_option. If you delete all the options for the product_ids that you specify.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Store Manager for Magento, custom options can be deleted using import/export (and without database tables clearing, which by the way can be dangerous). Simply filter out products with custom options, export them and while importing the file back, at the last step of import process select the option "Delete custom options that exist in source .csv file", check the screen-capture - http://screencast.com/t/WUxppoO3x5

Comment: I tried using this feature however the options will first be deleted and then re-added based on what is in the file. Unless I've misunderstood your direction, this solution wasn't able to clear our the custom items and keep them cleared out.